# Similarity between $A$ and $B (2\times 2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find out whether $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 1 \\
    -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ are similar. Both matrices have the same trace, same rank, same determinant and the same eigenvalues. So I think they are similar. The eigenvalues are $3, 2$. Now I'm not sure how to find if they are indeed similar.

I am trying to find if there is a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ that contains only eigenvectors but when trying to solve $(3 I - A)v = 0$ there is no solution... What should I do from here?

Answer (score 2):

Similarity is an equivalence relation (prove it). So if $A$ and $B$ are similar to the same matrix, then they are similar.

Since the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same (and distinct), they both are similar to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so they're similar. No other computation is needed.

Comment: Why are they both similar to this matrix? I think I need to show that the eigenvectors are a valid basis for $M_[x]^{\mathbb{R^2}}$ first

Comment: @Joe928 Both matrices have $3$ and $2$ as eigenvalues, so they're diagonalizable; the order of eigenvalues along the diagonal is immaterial, because it just corresponds to a permutation of the basis of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a solution for $(3I-A)v=0$: all vectors $(x,0) $.

In general, if an $n\times n $ matrix has $n $ distinct eigenvalues,  then it is diagonalizable, so your matrices are indeed similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

(1) Find the eigenvectors for each of the matrices.

(2) Consider the map $M$ that takes the eigenvectors for $A$ to the eigenvectors for $B$ with corresponding eigenvalues.

(3) Consider $M^{-1}BM$.

Why does this work: Let $\lambda_1\not=\lambda_2$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.  Let $v_1,v_2$ be the (corresponding) eigenvectors of $A$ and $w_1,w_2$ be the (corresponding) eigenvectors of $B$.  Then $Av_i=\lambda_iv_i$.  On the other hand, $M^{-1}BMv_i=M^{-1}Bw_i=M^{-1}\lambda_iw_i=\lambda_iM^{-1}w_i=\lambda_iv_i$.  Basically $A$ and $B$ act the same way on the corresponding eigenvectors, so by mapping one to the other, they act the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=PDP^{-1}$, and $B=QDQ^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $2$ and $3$, then $A=PQ^{-1}BQP^{-1}$, and you have done.